# Manager ran out of work to give us. Must I stay in the office and do nothing?

Tags: professionalism, company-policy, legal

I work at a call center. Each day we are assigned new calling pools and it sort of is possible to actually run out of work once the pool becomes exhausted. Usually we can find ways to “prolong” the work such as calling back people we couldn’t get a hold of, or leave messages. But today we completely ran out of work. The manager told us to clean the office area. Two things 1) the office didn’t need cleaning and we didn’t really know where things were to go so we haphazardly wasted time e.g. wipe down the computer keyboards, arrange magazines in alphabetical order etc. 2) I am really really bad at cleaning, especially when I’m just told to do a “general tidy up”, my eyes don’t perceive mess.
This was only a temporary job as the work is limited. I’m afraid tomorrow is going to be even worse and we’re just going to make a mess so we can clean it up again and I really don’t like this. Do I have to stay? What are my options? I will be quitting soon but would like a good reference.

Aside: my personal philosophy is people should get paid for getting something done, and not just sitting at their desk at a certain time. The company/management seems to have the mindset “you need to be at your desk between 12-5”. I find it frustrating as there are a lot of things I can be doing than sitting at a desk wasting time.

Comment: Do you expect to be paid for the full hours, or only for the time worked?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I expect to get paid for doing work. Since just sitting there is not doing work, it is against my principles to get paid for it. If what you meant is, would I expect to get paid if I left the office, then of course not.

Comment: @JoeT do you have an number of hours you are expected to work? Other than that there is a reason why alot of workplaces allow toys and have Entertainment systems :D

Comment: @JoeT You might ask your manager, "It seems there's not so much calling to do today. Would you mind if I clocked out early?". In some call centers, this is totally okay. But you must be up front about it. No pretending that you're working the whole shift. And if your manager does want you to stay around "to tidy up", then be prepared to do that, even if you think it's a waste of time.

Comment: I think almost all work contracts say something like "(Normal tasks) and other related work assigned"

Comment: Related: [Does it look bad if I leave early as an hourly employee?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65501/does-it-look-bad-if-i-leave-early-as-an-hourly-employee/)

Comment: @JoeT "Since just sitting there is not doing work, it is against my principles to get paid for it."  You're too idealistic.  There are always tradeoffs in any job.  Usually you can't "have it all."  In this particular case, the work doesn't sound interesting anyway, so IMHO your goals should be getting paid and career development.  If your employer isn't competent enough to keep you busy on meaningful tasks, that's their problem, not yours.  I'd stick around, collect the pay, do what you're instructed, and in any free time do career dev, however you construe that.

Comment: You're paid to be at work, doing whatever it is (within reason) that the company requires of you. The vast majority of employment contracts include a phrase such as "And other suitable duties as required by the company"... either way, you're being paid to be there, not to do a specific task.

Comment: Duplicate of past questions about what to do when you run out of assigned work, I think. (Android app **still** makes citing them unnecessarily difficult.)

Comment: "my personal philosophy is people should get paid for getting something done" - and how does your personal philosophy correlate to the work contract you did sign? Without going into what is usual - your philosophy is irrelevant if you agreed to something else in your work contract.

Answer (score 8):

My mother worked at a call center for 20 years, and I can guarantee she's kicked enough rocks to build a wall between Mexico and the United States Trump would be proud of.

Why would the manager make you guys stay late? Think about it from the manager's perspective, if he tells you guys that you can leave early and still get paid salary for finishing the job early, then what will happen? You guys will probably race to the finish each day. With an industry where service is key, rushed behavior can drastically degenerate performance. He wants to avoid this, and I hope you can understand why.

Yes, you probably will have to stay. As far as options go you could find another job that's performance based(think carpentry or other skill based trade.) or you could find another call center with a different work culture. From the sounds of it this is the best option. I would personally recommend looking through your network for possible openings(People always want to help, most of the time they just don't know how.)

Comment: "Think about it from the manager's perspective,..."  It's also possible that the  manager is doing this only to look good to people above him/her.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing out the job site info since that's not really pertinent to the question and cannot possibly be exhaustive even if it were.

Answer (score 8):

> I find it frustrating as there are a lot of things I can be doing than sitting at a desk wasting time.

Well I hate to break it to you but that's basically what work is. It's a business transaction where you trade your time for your employer's money. In return your employer gets to tell you how to spend that time and your energy during that time. In the US in particular, an employer and their chosen representatives (managers) are very free in what they can ask you to do. With at-will employment you are also free to decline and find another job. So with that context, it's perfectly fine for your manager to tell you to sit at your desk idle as long as he pays you for that time. It's a bad business practice to have idle workers but it's typical for some industries.

> Do I have to stay?

If you want to remain employed yes. It's generally unwise to ignore your manager's instructions.

> What are my options?

It depends on the job and your profile. Generally you go to your manager and ask him what you can do when you've run out of work. Sometimes you can suggest your own projects but that's difficult in a call centre which has a very specific role. But even those typically have administrative work or a backlog of Things That Need Doing.

Showing this kind of initiative is important because if this situation becomes common, that's a clear sign that **the company has employed too many people for their workload. In a call centre that typically heralds lay-offs** as the workforce is reduced to meet the lower demand. If you've shown some professionalism and willingness to take on odd jobs or work on personal development instead of browsing the web, you're more likely to be among the people who are kept on. Either way **it's a sign that you should be searching for a new job**, though I gather that you're already doing that.

> I will be quitting soon but would like a good reference.

Then you'll need to remain professional and show initiative. See the previous section.

Comment: "It's a business transaction where you trade your time for your employer's money. In return your employer gets to tell you how to spend that time and your energy during that time."  Yep.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You are not paid to get work done. Unless you have a contract which says you are getting paid only if you perform work x to amount y. What you are paid for is to get work done, when there is work to be done. In your case, there is currently no work to do, and even if your supervisor confirms this - enjoy the quiet times! You can for example use it for developing your work relevant skills by reading related stuff in the internet. But ask your boss first.

Comment: Unfortunately we're not allowed to surf the internet (even for work related development). Any other suggestions how to kill time?

Comment: "You are not paid to get work done." what do you mean by this?

Comment: @JoeT If you have no Internet access, then read a book, magazine, etc. at slow times while waiting for a call.

Comment: @JoeT "You are not paid to get work done." I think they mean't if you have a contract for hours x Pay. So if you sit there and do nothing you could still get paid because you are on the clock and they wanted you to be at work for those hours. Example I used to work at a restaurant and sometimes there would be nothing to do but clean the kitchen and then after that it was still empty I would still get payed for another hour of doing nothing til they just sent me home.

Answer (score 3):

If you work in a call center, you are likely paid by the hour, so they naturally expect you there for every hour that they are paying you.

Looking at this from a business perspective, you may not be in the only call center the company has. I was the network support for a call center once and sometimes we had to take workload unexpectedly from another center because they had a power outage or a network issue. And sometimes the calls are returned or the workload suddenly picks up. You can't come back from home to pick up the work of a call coming in right now. This is likely the reason they can't release you. **They may need you on short notice to pick up calls.**

I'd suggest bringing reading material. Or you could get with your call center trainer to see about putting together some refresher training for slack times. Or perhaps you could work on organization something for charity? Of course check with your boss before doing any of those things. Call centers tend to be pretty micromanaged.